# JSON_ARRAY not sending an empty list on MariaDB

Tags: sql, arrays, json, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have a problem in MariaDB (10.3.18) when I use  `JSON_ARRAY` function, if my subqueries doesn't have any results it doesn't give me an empty array, it gives me a array with 1 null results.

Exemple:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY() // -> [] this is what I want to obtain

SELECT JSON_ARRAY((
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'id', id,
            'name', name
        )
    )
    FROM user
    WHERE user.acive = TRUE
)) // -> [null] If I don't have any result
```

For the moment I found a way to counter this problem by using `REPLACE` function like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(JSON_ARRAY(null), "[null]", "[]")
```

But if there was something to tell MariaDB to send an empty result and not a NULL result it could help me a lot!

Comment: MySQL version??

Comment: My bad : it's MariaDB 10.3.18 (not MySQL) I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

An option using [IFNULL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/ifnull/):

```sql
SELECT
  IFNULL(
    (SELECT
      CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'id', `user`.`id`,
          'name', `user`.`name`
        )
      ), ']')
    FROM `user`
    WHERE `user`.`active` = true),
    JSON_ARRAY()
  );
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0aab1bde1a52b5b8c2e6ecb92004a014).